# Get Music files details only

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

Basically I am trying to get the details of a music file inside an android device (Ex. The music's title, artist, etc) and store them to a `list<>`. 
(`SongData` contains the list, and it contains a list of `Song` object.)

```
public void PopulateSongList(Context context) {
        SongData songData = new SongData();
        Android.Net.Uri musicUri = Android.Provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.ExternalContentUri;
        //Used to query the media files.
        ICursor musicCursor = context.ContentResolver.Query(musicUri, null, null, null, null);

        if (musicCursor != null && musicCursor.MoveToFirst())
        {
            int songID = 0;

            //get columns.
            int songTitleColumn = musicCursor.GetColumnIndex("title");
            int songArtistColumn = musicCursor.GetColumnIndex("artist");

            //add songs to list
            do
            {
                String songTitle = musicCursor.GetString(songTitleColumn);
                //Tried, but file name does not contain file extension.
                if (songTitle.ToLower().Contains(".mp4") || songTitle.ToLower().Contains(".m4a"))
                {
                    String songArtist = musicCursor.GetString(songArtistColumn);
                    songData.AddNewSong(new Song(++songID, songTitle, songArtist, null));
                }
            }
            while (musicCursor.MoveToNext());
        }
    }
```

The code works well but however in the `do..while` loop, `songTitle` also contains other files that are not music files as well. 
I tried checking for file extensions but it does not work, and after using the debugger again, the file name given does not contain the file extension.

So how do I make sure that it only grabs details from a music file, and not other kind of files?
(Also, I want to grab the name of the artist of a music file, but apparently `int songArtistColumn = musicCursor.GetColumnIndex("artist");` does not seem to work.)

Finally, how do I get the image of a music file? (The song image).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `musicCursor.GetColumnNames()` to see what the file is allowing you to work with.

[Here's an image of the possible results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdZUw.png)  you can get if you execute it.
`musicCursor.GetColumnNames()` will return the results in a `string[]` so you can use `List<string> songInfo = new List<string>(string[]);`

A problem you might get is a `NullException`, this happens when the data you're trying to work with have a value of null. You'll get this value directly from the file if the Artist or other values are unknown.

I don't know where the Image file is stored, but if it's stored with the music file it will most likely be stored in a `byte[]`. So you'll need to convert the `byte[]` to an image.